# Where is the apple.com favicon hosted?

Tags: favicon

I know how to find a favicon (or so I thought) but this site is different:

http://www.apple.com/

See if you can find out where their favicon is (if you would paste the link to it if you find it).

I was just gonna analyze it, but now it is a matter of principal that I couldn't find it :)

Comment: Well http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico seems to work - is that what you meant?

Comment: I think the salient bit of the question here is "or so I thought" :-) Obviously, you thought wrong. In any case, it hardly seems to be a programming related question.

Comment: Yes it was... I was not sure if they were using a different method of injecting the icon (ex. using javascript to add a tag in the header with an embedded ico or something). Moreover, hardly a reason to -1 the question

Comment: @Rup, Thanks! Didn't know that was a standard... Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like they aren't using proper tags in `<head>` but just slapping it into http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico

Answer (score -1):

http://apple.com/favicon.ico -- just verified this file exists